# How to recalculate values between columns in accordance with the ratio by the script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this script. It works for values but getting an error #NUMBER! (#ЧИСЛО!) on header row (row 1)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF9Tu.png). Where I'm wrong? 
I think it's the problem of getting range onEdit() but I can not be sure in it.
I tried to modify typeof like `typeof e.value === 'number' ? 'string' : e.value` or `typeof e.value !== 'number' ? "": e.value` and `typeof e.value !== 'number' ? e.value : ""` but it's doesn't work as I want.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const value = (typeof e.value === 'number' ? "" : e.value);
  Logger.log(value);
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  

  // Get the "Coordinates" of the edit
  let startColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log(startColumn);
  let startRow = e.range.getRow();

  // Get the ratios at the edited row
  let hRatio = sheet.getRange(startRow, 8).getValue();
  let iRatio = sheet.getRange(startRow, 9).getValue();
  
  // Get array limit
  let finalval = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  let final = finalval.filter(String).length;
  let valueAlt = sheet.getRange(startRow, 6).getValue();
  switch(startRow > 1 && startRow < (final + 1)) {
    case startColumn == 5: // Edit on E column
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 6).setValue(value * (1 - hRatio)); //Update F Cell 
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 7).setValue(value * (1 - hRatio) * (1 - iRatio)); // Update G Cell
        break;
    case startColumn == 6:     
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 5).setValue(value / (1 - hRatio)); 
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 7).setValue(value * (1 - iRatio)); 
        break;
    case startColumn == 7: // Edit on G column
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 5).setValue(value / (1 - hRatio) / (1 - iRatio));
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 6).setValue(value / (1 - iRatio));
        break;
    case startColumn == 3: // Edit on C column
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 5).setValue(valueAlt / (1 - hRatio)); // Update on E cell
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 7).setValue(valueAlt * (1 - iRatio));
        break;  
    case startColumn == 4: // Edit on D column
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 5).setValue(valueAlt / (1 - hRatio)); // Update on E cell
        sheet.getRange(startRow, 7).setValue(valueAlt * (1 - iRatio)); 
        break; 
    default: break;

  }


}
```

I think it's the problem of range onEdit() but I don't understand where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way for you it's to use an early exit from the function.

Just check `startRow === 1` before do something.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const startRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (startRow === 1) return;
  const value = e.value;
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  ... blah blah blah
}
```